# Is there some way i could perform multiple operations without reopening it again and again?

Tags: python

I have made a "simple" calculator. It works perfectly though no errors but when I execute the .py file and use it in the command prompt it just performs one operation (i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication or division) and then exits.

Is there some way I could perform more operations without reopening it again and again?

Comment: Use an infinite loop? `while(True)...`

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop and `raw_input()`:

```
while True:
    operator = raw_input('Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ')
    first = raw_input('Enter your first term: ')
    second = raw_input('Enter your second term: ')
    if operator.lower.startswith('a'):
        print first+second
    elif operator.lower.startswith('m'):
        print first*second
    elif operator.lower.startswith('s'):
        print first-second
    elif operator.lower.startswith('d'):
        print float(first)/second
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this defined method:

```
def main():
    num1 = raw_input("First Number?: ")
    num2 = raw_input("Second Number?: ")
    opsym = raw_input("Would you like to add, subtract, divide, or multiply?: ")
    if opsym == "add":
        #add
        #printres
        time.sleep(2.5)
        main()
    elif opsym == "subtract":
        #subtract
        #printres
        time.sleep(2.5)
        main()
    elif opsym == "multiply":
        #multiply
        #printres
        time.sleep(2.5)
        main()
    elif opsym == "divide":
        #divide
        #printres
        time.sleep(2.5)
        main()
main()
```

This is personally easiest for me to keep track of and use. `time.sleep()` is optional, however, it gives the reader time to note the result before moving on.

Comment: This is bad, python doesn't have tail call unrolling, so this will crash at the 1000th operation, when the max program stack limit is reached.

Comment: @LieRyan Ever seen a 1000 question math test? Me niether! On a side note, i had never heard of that; then again, id never tested it either :d